# String together all Punctation and symbols into one string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to create a vector for a dataframe which has all of the punctation and symbols form the [:punct:] class in R. Is there any way to print out the contents of the class rather than trying to string together all of the characters? Just seems like you have to escape each character and paste them all manually into the string, which seems extremely tedious.

These are all the symbols:

```
! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [  ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.
#code so far
symbols <- c(' ! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [  ] ^ _ ` { | } ~. ')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your task: just to collect all the symbols from the class in one string or to delete all of these symbols from another string?

Comment: Collect all the symbols from a class into a string

Comment: try and find the relevant raw numbers ... ie `rawToChar(as.raw(1:200))`

Comment: You need the TRE `punct`, right? Not the PCRE or ICU `\p{P}`? From what I see, you got the symbols already, what else do you need? Escaping can be done with a `gsub`, but why? *Is there any way to print out the contents of the class rather than trying to string together all of the characters?* - **NO**.

Comment: `grep('[[:punct:]]', sapply(as.raw(1:255), rawToChar), value = TRUE)`

Comment: @rawr you should post as an answer . ( checking rawr's answer `rawToChar(as.raw(c(33:47, 58:64, 91:96, 123:126)))` [codes from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) )

Comment: @user20650 I just stole your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert from raw to character and then `grep` for predefined classes:

```
(rch <- as.raw(0:255))
# [1] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 ...

(ch <- rawToChar(rch, TRUE))
# [1] "" "\001" "\002" "\003" "\004" "\005" "\006" "\a"   "\b"   "\t"   "\n"   "\v"   "\f"  ...


## change locale to avoid warnings
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')

dput(grep('[[:punct:]]', ch, value = TRUE))
# c("!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", 
#   "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "[", "\\", 
#   "]", "^", "_", "`", "{", "|", "}", "~")
```

`?regex` describes these classes:

> `[:alnum:]`
>   Alphanumeric characters: `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]`.
>
> `[:alpha:]`
>   Alphabetic characters: `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]`.
>
> `[:blank:]`
>   Blank characters: space and tab, and possibly other locale-dependent characters such as non-breaking space.
>
> `[:cntrl:]`
>   Control characters. In ASCII, these characters have octal codes 000 through 037, and 177 (DEL). In another character set, these are the equivalent characters, if any.
>
> `[:digit:]`
>   Digits: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
>
> `[:graph:]`
>   Graphical characters: [:alnum:] and [:punct:].
>
> `[:lower:]`
>   Lower-case letters in the current locale.
>
> `[:print:]`
>   Printable characters: `[:alnum:]`, `[:punct:]` and space.
>
> `[:punct:]`
>   Punctuation characters:
>     ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.
>
> `[:space:]`
>   Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters.
>
> `[:upper:]`
>   Upper-case letters in the current locale.
>
> `[:xdigit:]`
>   Hexadecimal digits:
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F a b c d e f.

So we can repeat the above with any of these

```
dput(grep('[[:space:]]', ch, value = TRUE))
# c("\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", " ")

dput(grep('[[:alnum:]]', ch, value = TRUE))
# c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", 
# "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
# "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", 
# "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
# "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
```

You can also use PCRE

```
dput(grep('\\s', ch, value = TRUE))
# c("\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", " ")

dput(grep('\\v|\\h', ch, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
# c("\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", " ", "\205", "\240")

dput(grep('\\p{P}', ch, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
# c("!", "\"", "#", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", ",", "-", ".", 
# "/", ":", ";", "?", "@", "[", "\\", "]", "_", "{", "}", "\241", 
# "\247", "\253", "\266", "\267", "\273", "\277")
```

Or define your own, etc

```
dput(grep('[\x20-\x7E]', ch, value = TRUE))
dput(grep('[A-c]', ch, value = TRUE))
```

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks so much. Is it possible to put all these symbols then into one long string? You would pretty much have to concatenate all the values together with paste, and lapply?

Comment: @petergensler; ise `paste(grep('[[:punct:]]', ch, value = TRUE), collapse="")`